# Why can't I call RemoveAt on an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, compiler-errors

Now, I know that in C#, arrays are a fixed-size collection. It makes sense that you couldn't use the `RemoveAt` method on them, [except that the `System.Array` class, which all array types extend from, implements the `System.Collections.IList` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), which requires a `RemoveAt` method.

If [you upcast an array to an `IList`, or pass it to a method taking an `IList` as an argument](https://tio.run/##VY1LC8IwEITP9lfssYXY@rpVBfEggoKoN/EQ0lAW2gSysSqlvz2mLb4Oy@58s8wIGgoSzt0IVQ6nJ1lZpsGvite6KKSwqBXFG6mkQZEGgSg4ERyMzg0voQ4GZLlFAZXGDPYcVUjW@JTLFbjJKWpfBhU3gLAAJe@e12M2YVM2a1JvHWWpK7myITIYRS1JEow/tEPNf8vbnJ@X4XaH1B5Q@M0AlfWTyUff28JvVm90eY1zLw), you can call `.RemoveAt` on it, which will throw a `NotSupportedException` at runtime. However, if I *don't* upcast it, [and call it directly](https://tio.run/##VY1LC8IwEITP9lfssYXY@rpVBfEggoKoN/EQ0lAW2gSysSqlvz2mLb4Oy@58s8wIGgoSzt0IVQ6nJ1lZpsGvite6KKSwqBXFG6mkQZEGgSg4ERyMzg0voQ4GZLlFAZXGDPYcVUjW@JTLFbjJKWpfBhU3gLAAJe@e12M2YVM2a1JvJclRlrqSKxsig1HUMow/rAPNf8vbnJ@X4XaH1B5Q@M0AlfWTyUff28JvVm90eY1zLw), it will cause a *compiler error* instead, `'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAt'`, despite the method clearly existing.

What allows the compiler to catch this `NotSupportedException` at compile time? Is it special-cased for arrays, or can I define my own classes to have this kind of behaviour?

Comment: `System.Array` implements `RemoveAt` as an explicit interface implementation, i.e. `IList.RemoveAt`, so it's not exposed just by name.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array really shouldn't implement IList because it does not fully implement that interface, hence the NotSupportedException, but it was likely added for convenience.

The reason that it doesn't compile when you call Array.RemoveAt is because Array implements that method of IList [explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) which means that the method isn't available unless it's cast as that interface.

This looks like:

```
class OnlySortOfAList : IList
{
  void IList.RemoveAt(int Index) // note the lack of access modifier
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: If arrays didn't implement `IList`, then it would not be possible to have a class which could wrap both `T[]` and `IList<T>` (e.g. for purposes of firing events when elements are modified), but supported the ability to add/remove elements when wrapping collections that support such abilities.  While `IList<T>` lacks an adequate means of reporting the an implementation can or cannot do, being able to write one wrapper that can handle all "partial" implementations of a "kitchen sink" interface is cleaner than having to write a separate wrapper class for each combination of features.

Answer (score 0):

Some kinds of numerically-indexed collections are resizable and some aren't.  If .NET had used separate interfaces for resizable and non-resizable collections, then it would not be possible to write a single wrapper class would allow clients to resize the wrapped collection, and yet be usable with collections that don't support resizing.  If code would need to wrap some collections that don't support resizing, but would also need to resize some that do, separate wrapper classes would have to be written for each purpose.

If code has a reference of an array type, the compiler will know what methods that type does and does not expose through references of that type.  Classes which will never be able to usefully process a certain method will generally not expose it through references of their own type, since code would not have reason to invoke such a method on references of that type.  If a class implements an interface, however, it must allow for the possibility that useless methods might be called by outside code which doesn't realize those methods are useless, and must thus include some kind of code for every method in the interface.

Although the actual mechanism for handling interfaces is different, it may be useful to think of interface functions as having special names, so if a class `Woozle` implements an interface `IWoozle` that contains method Foo() and implicitly implements that interface with its own function Foo(), it will actually contain two methods: `public void Foo();` and `public void IWoozle▪Foo() { Foo(); }  // Not the actual name`.

If a class `Zoozle` implements IWoozle.Foo explicitly, then it would only implement the latter method.  Given `Woozle x; Zoozle y;`, a compiler given `x.Foo()` or `y.Foo()` would look for a method called `Foo()` (which `Woozle` has, but `Zoozle` doesn't).  Given `IWoozle x1=x, y1=y;`, a compiler given `x1.Foo()` or `y1.Foo()` would look for `IWoozle▪Foo`, which it would find in both `x` and `y`.